# why when I try to join one view embed with php from control to another view fails?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to embed my second view to my first view, but when I try to do it then my variable profile from my controller fails when I try to do this , how could I fix this?is there a way to do this?

main view

```
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content">
            <section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
                <?php $this->load->view('signup/signup'); ?>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

second view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('assets/dist/css/singup.css');?>">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="logbox">
            <form id="signup" method="post">
                <h1>create an account</h1>
                <input name="user[name]" type="text" placeholder="What's your username?" pattern="^[\w]{3,16}$" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" class="input pass" />
                <select name="profile_id" id="profile_id">
                    <option value="">Select a Profile</option>
                    <?php foreach ($profile as $value): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>"><?php echo $value['profile']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
                <input name="user[password]" type="password" placeholder="Choose a password" required="required" class="input pass" />
                <input name="user[password2]" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" required="required" class="input pass" />
                <input name="user[email]" type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="input pass" />
                <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!" class="inputButton" />
                <div class="text-center">
                    already have an account? <a href="#" id="login_id">login</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->load->vars($data)` instead of passing data in second argument in `$this->load->view('main', $data)`.

Example controller method code:

```
//you create $data array to be passed to view
$this->load->vars($data);
$this->load->view('main');
```

This way variables are available to all view files no matter of loading order.

[Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).